# In Python's multiprocessing package, why is there multiprocessing.Pool and multiprocessing.pool.Pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

While learning about Python's `multiprocessing` package (for [Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing)), I noticed `multiprocessing.Pool` is defined in the Class `BaseContext` in `context.py`.  This definition is

```
   def Pool(self, processes=None, initializer=None, initargs=(),
         maxtasksperchild=None):
    '''Returns a process pool object'''
    from .pool import Pool
    return Pool(processes, initializer, initargs, maxtasksperchild,
                context=self.get_context())
```

Thus, it ends up calling `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` defined in `pool.py`.

Why does the `multiprocessing` package define both `multiprocessing.Pool` and `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`?

Comment: Maybe so you can override its pool manager with your own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`context.py` contains OS-dependent code. The `Pool` and many other values are
defined differently depending on whether `sys.platform == 'win32'` or not.

The `pool.py` module contains code related the creation of a Pool *given a
context*.

By organizing the code in this way, the developer manages to write `pool.py` in an OS-agnostic way. There are no `if sys.platform ...` statements in pool.py, for example.

---

The `__init__.py` contains:

```
globals().update((name, getattr(context._default_context, name))
                 for name in context._default_context.__all__)
__all__ = context._default_context.__all__
```

which copies values from `context._default_context` into the `multiprocessing` packages' namespace. This is how `multiprocessing.Pool` gets defined.

As a user of the `multiprocessing` package, you are expected to access the Pool
via `multiprocessing.Pool`, although it is possible to use
`multiprocessing.pool.Pool` too.